# Java multicast client server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I try to create a program which is based on client/server communication.
In this program I have several clients and several servers.
At the beginning of the program some clients go up, and wait for new connections from different servers.
When the first server goes up, I want him to know who is the clients that are available in the network, and then it begins to communicate with all these clients in tcp protocol (ServerSocket).
However, if a new clients goes up, this server should know about it.
The same happens when new servers go up.

My first think, is to use multicast commnication. The client will send every 5 seconds a broadcast to the networks and the servers will listen to these messages.
My broblem is how to combine these two methods (multicast and tcp) in order to built this program.
Should I use two differnet ports one for the multicast, and one for the tcp protocol?
Is it possible to allow the server\client to listen for different communication (multicast or tcp) with treads?

I just need a litle push, and some basic code in order to begin this...

**EDIT:** OK, I succeeded to built a multicast comunication.
The agent goes up, and send every 5 seconds its name.
the server goes up, and receives the agent's broadcast. 
If a new agent goes up, the server know about it.

The code look like this:

**Agent code:**

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.DatagramSocket;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.SocketException;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Agent {
        private static int portMulticasting = 1004;

        private DatagramSocket socket;
        private boolean broadcast =  true;
        private String group = "230.0.0.1"; //group address
        private int delay = 5000;

        public Agent(){
            try{
                socket = new DatagramSocket();
                System.out.println("agent ready");
            }
            catch (SocketException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        public void start(String agentName){
            DatagramPacket packet;
            try{
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(group);
                while (broadcast){
                    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                    buf = agentName.getBytes();
                    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length,address,portMulticasting);
                    socket.send(packet);
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(delay);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e){
                        System.exit(0);
                    }   
                }
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

            System.out.println("Enter name of the new agent: ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String agentName = sc.nextLine();

            Agent agent = new Agent();
            agent.start(agentName);
       }
   }
```

**Server Code:**

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.MulticastSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.util.Scanner;



    public class Server {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String groupIP = "230.0.0.1";
            int portMulticasting = 1004;
            if (args.length > 0)
                groupIP = args[0];
            try{
                //get a multicast socket and join group
                MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(portMulticasting);
                InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(groupIP);
                socket.joinGroup(group);
                //get packet
                DatagramPacket packet;
                while (true){
                    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length);
                    socket.receive(packet);
                    buf = packet.getData();
                    int len = packet.getLength();
                    String received = (new String(buf)).substring(0,len);
                    try{
                        System.out.println("Agent name: " + received);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                        System.out.println("cannot interpret number");
                    }
                }
                socket.leaveGroup(group);
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   }
```

Now, I want that the agents continue to send broadcast every 5 seconds, but meanwhile the server begin to work with the agents (send messages, ask for information from the agents etc).

Comment: I thought it is the server responsibility to "listen" for a client request. but in your case, it is the other way around.

Comment: Why? Once the clients connect via TCP, the server knows about them. What value is added by the multicasting?

Comment: The client doesn't know who are the servers in the network. It can be one server, but it can be also several servers.

Comment: That's a reason for the *servers* to multicast themselves *to the clients.* Not the other way around.

Comment: the servers and the clients don't know about each other. that why, I must begin my communication with a broadcast that comes from the client. After that the servers who have received this broadcast will open a  tcp connection to the client. @EJP